# XML2CSV conversion Filter Columns with Condition | *nix OS

Tags: xml, linux, xml-parsing, export-to-csv

I am converting my XML file to CSV using [XML2CSV](http://code.google.com/p/xml2csv-conv/)

The XML format can be simplified to

```
<PersonalInfo>
    <UserDetail>
       <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
       <Occupation>Student</Occupation>
       <DateOfBirth>08/14/1999</DateOfBirth>
    </UserDetail>
    <CaseDetail>....</CaseDetail>
    <TransactionDetail></TransactionDetail>
</PersonalInfo>      
<PersonalInfo>
    <UserDetail>
       <FirstName>XYZ</FirstName>
       <Occupation>Student</Occupation>
       <DateOfBirth>04/25/1991</DateOfBirth>
     </UserDetail>
     <CaseDetail>....</CaseDetail>
     <TransactionDetail></TransactionDetail>
</PersonalInfo>      
<PersonalInfo>
    <UserDetail>
        <FirstName>DEF</FirstName>
        <Occupation>Teacher</Occupation>
        <DateOfBirth>05/12/1984</DateOfBirth>
    </UserDetail>
    <CaseDetail>....</CaseDetail>
    <TransactionDetail></TransactionDetail>
</PersonalInfo>
```

While using the XML to CSV converter i only want to convert those fields where the Occupation tag has value of Student. Is it possible through this or i have to use some other script to make a final xml file, then convert that to CSV. Any Ideas.

EDIT: Only Values of FirstName, Occupation and DateOfBirth are needed. No value from CaseDetail or TransactionDetail should be in the resultant file.
The format of the end file should be like

```
 ABC|Student|08/14/1999 
 XYZ|Student|04/25/1991
```

Comment: use xslt and an xslt processor, though then you could also just skip the whole xml2csv step.  the template looks like `match="Occupation='Student'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending my comment to a real answer now.  Here's the xslt I used to convert the xml to csv directly.  (I used libxml2's `xsltproc` to do the actual conversion)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="PersonalInfo">
    <!-- causes only UserDetail nodes to be processed -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="UserDetail"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UserDetail[Occupation='Student']">
    <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Occupation"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="DateOfBirth"/>
    <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- catch all the other userdetail here -->
  <xsl:template match="UserDetail"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your xml this gives:

```
ABC,Student,08/14/1999
XYZ,Student,04/25/1991
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer. But i have an issue. The Above xml was a part of the detailed file that i have your code works well on this selected chunk. Now What to apply if my XML takes the following Format.
>      <Persons>
>         <UserDetail>....</UserDetail>
    <CaseDetail>....</CaseDetail>      
    <TransactionDetail>....</TransactionDetail>      
</Persons>
And i have to strip the information from this format....

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Can you also tell me how do i avoid header tags to be included in output. like my xml starts with some info tags like <dateCreation> and <authorName> and then the main xml so how can i strip these tags value from output.

Comment: just define a template for them that's empty: `<xsl:template match="dateCreation"/>` and `<xsl:template match="authorName"/>`